# Do smaller parties have front- and backbenchers?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

Are MPs belonging to parties that are neither in government, nor in [Her Majesty's Most Loyal Opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_Majesty%27s_Most_Loyal_Opposition_(United_Kingdom)), divide their MPs between frontbanchers and backbenchers?  Or are essentially all the MPs for parties like SNP and Liberal Democrats backbenchers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of seating in the House of Commons, this is [governed by custom](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-32802374) rather than strict rules, but both the Liberal Democrats and SNP have (when the third largest party) seated themselves with some MPs on the front row of opposition benches.

In terms of pure nomenclature, the [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontbench_Team_of_Angus_Robertson) and the [Liberal Democrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Democrat_frontbench_team) have both  designated leadership groups of MPs variously called a front bench team or shadow cabinet.